# Count occurences of strings from list in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count

I have a list of strings, e.g: booknames = [Book name 1, Book name 2, Book name 3, ....]

I also have a text file in such format:
logfile.txt

`X person borrowed Book name 1 on Y date 
 Z person borrowed Book name 2 on D date
...`

I want to know the amount of times each book has been borrowed. So I need to count the occurences of each element from list 'booknames' in the logfile. Preferably the results will be on a different list, for example:

Booknames = [ A , b , c , d]

list generated:
Occurence = [ 1 , 4 , 5 , 0]

I've tried dictianory methods however that didn't seem to work so I'm stuck trying to get the count.

Something I've tried:

`

```
file  = open('logfile.txt', 'r').read()
        b = bookname
        count = file.count(b)

        print(count)
```

`

But this doesn't work because bookname is a list and not a string. Therefore my thought is to create a for loop where it checks for occurences on every element of list bookname, however I don't have the knowledge to create one which would work, nor could I find one that suits my needs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far, and the specific error or problem you're facing.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I've put what I thought of so far, it's awful.

Comment: if you have list then you have to use `for`-loop. If you try it then show this code in question - maybe you used it incorrectly.

Comment: Why are `b = bookname` and `count = file.count(b)` indented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have list then you should use `for`-loop to check every element from list separately. And result you should `append()` to list for results.

```
booknames = ['Book name 1', 'Book name 2', 'Book name 3']
occurences = []

#text = open('logfile.txt', 'r').read()
text = '''X person borrowed Book name 1 on Y date 
Z person borrowed Book name 2 on D date
...'''

for name in booknames:
    count = text.count(name)
    occurences.append(count)

print(occurences)
```

Result

```
[1, 1, 0]
```

---

BTW: If every line has similar structure then maybe you could get every line and cut off book name from line and use `collections.Counter` to count names.

```
import collections 

booknames = ['Book name 1', 'Book name 2', 'Book name 3']
occurences = collections.Counter()

#fh = open('logfile.txt')
fh = '''X person borrowed Book name 1 on Y date 
Z person borrowed Book name 2 on D date
...'''.splitlines()

for line in fh:
    parts = line.split('borrowed', 1)

    if len(parts) < 2:
        print("Can't find 'borrowed' in", line)
        continue

    parts = parts[1].rsplit('on', 1)

    if len(parts) < 0:
        print("Can't find 'on' in", line)
        continue

    name = parts[0].strip()
    print('found:', name)
    occurences.update([name])

print(occurences)
```

Result

```
Found: Book name 1
Found: Book name 2
Can't find 'borrowed' in ...
Counter({'Book name 1': 1, 'Book name 2': 1})
```

And then you can use `booknames` with `Counter`

```
for name in booknames:
    print(name, 'occures', occurences[name], 'times')
```

Result

```
Book name 1 occures 1 times
Book name 2 occures 1 times
Book name 3 occures 0 times
```

Or as list

```
result = []
for name in booknames:
    result.append( occurences[name] )

print(result)
```

or shorter with list comprehension

```
result = [ occurences[name] for name in booknames ]
```

Comment: The first part of your answer works just as I wanted it to, now I can use booklist and occurence to create a graph like I wanted to. Thank you.